# svndumpfilter2 not working well with branches

Tags: svn, svndumpfilter

I want to create a new repository from a folder in my current repository (trunk/a/b).

The problem is that we worked a lot with branches and copied files from the branches to the folder in trunk - this is why I use svndumpfilter2 instead of the original svndumpfilter.

However, there is still a problem that happens where there is a revision in which files were copied from a branch and in the same revision there are modified filed from the trunk. In that case, svndumpfilter2 crashes because it is looking for the original files (from the branch).

Is there a way to bypass this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your primary SVN server, you may want to try this implementation of the svndumpfilter:

https://github.com/jasperlee108/svndumpfilterIN

It relies on `svnlook` to pull in previous excluded paths to prevent "tangling".